# Hide a record in Edit Page Layout

Tags: page-layout

[image]Hi, I have been trying to hide a section in a layout with no success, the requirement is to hide it in new/edit page layout and not in the details page. I tested the option to use the section properties, and it works when I use it with System Information section, but not with the one I created. Does anyone know why is this happening or if I missed some steps?

As an additional information, it works perfectly on Classic, but I need it in Lightning.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just to clarify -- you are trying to hide the section header or the whole section?

Comment: The whole section, most of the fields are not filled by the end user, so those fields were moved to a new section, and we're trying to hide it only in the New/Edit page, and visible in detail page. The section properties seems to be the solution but not sure why doesn't have the expected behavior.

Comment: so - in classic, those options affect the section header only; new/edit will never display fields that user doesn't have Edit FLS. So, to hide in new/edit, ensure user doesn't have edit FLS. Otherwise, you need dynamic forms in Lightning which only work for custom objects as of Summer 21